# How do use a GridSearch to search the parameters of a model in a pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I need to use grid search to search the parameters of  `model` in `my_pipeline`  How can I do this?

I don't want to search te parameters of the pipeline instead I want to search the parameters of the model that is inside the pipeline

````
Or_pipeline =  make_pipeline(OR_preprocessor,model)
XGB_model = XGBRegressor()
params = {'learning_rate': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1],
         'n_estimators': [200,400.600,800,1000]}

grid_search_XGB = GridSearchCV(estimator = OR_pipeline ,param_grid= params,scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error',
                              n_jobs =1,
                              cv=3)

grid_search_XGB.fit(x_train,y_train)```

 

ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('columntransformer',
                 ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('or', OrdinalEncoder(),
                                                  ['country', 'store',
                                                   'product'])])),
                ('xgbregressor',
                 XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', ...))]).
````

Comment: Maybe see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html but you also have an error regarding the data types (categorical value) being passed to the xgboost model

Comment: Can you post an example of x_train and y_train that does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual practice is running grid search on the pipeline, i.e `grid_search_XGB = GridSearchCV(estimator = my_pipeline, ...)`. (See the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672914/attribute-error-pipeline-object-has-no-attribute-best-estimator/72728273#72728273).) You'll need to supply prefixes to your `params` names according to pipeline stage naming. This also allows tuning the preprocessing stage parameters if needed.

Comment: Thanks! how can I supply the prefixes so that the GridSearch looks searches the parameters of the model and not the pipeline? 
`OR_pipeline = make_pipeline(OR_preprocessor,model)
params = {'learning_rate': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1],
         'n_estimators': [200,400.600,800,1000]}

grid_search_XGB = GridSearchCV(OR_pipeline, param_grid= params, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error',
                              n_jobs =1,
                              cv=3)

grid_search_XGB.fit(x_train,y_train)`

Comment: `make_pipeline()` assigns stage names as a lowercased class names, so that would be: `params = {'xgbregressor__learning_rate': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1], 'xgbregressor__n_estimators': [200,400.600,800,1000]}`